# Not able to access maven dependency from a common folder in same directory

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-2

I am using a multi-module approach in Spring boot application. My directory structure is like

```
package name
|_bom
|__common-test
|__service
   |_src/test/java/TestFile.java
```

I have put test related dependencies in `pom.xml` of `common-test` and accessing them in test folder of service. I am able to access most of the dependencies in `TestFile.java` but not the dependency mentioned below. This is the last dependency in `pom.xml` of `common-test`. Following the same structure I am able to use mockito dependency but not this one.

I have defined related properties in `bom/pom.xml` which are to be used in `common-test/pom.xml`. Using this approach for first time and not sure how to achieve this. Basically, I need to maintain test related dependencies in `common-test` `pom.xml` and not include it in `service`.

`import org.junit.jupiter.migrationsupport.rules.EnableRuleMigrationSupport;`

`pom.xml` of `common-test` have this dependency

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>projeectname</artifactId>
        <groupId>in.packagename.mint</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>projeectname-common-test</artifactId>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>in.packagename.mint</groupId>
                <artifactId>projeectname-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <!-- project dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-migrationsupport</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

`pom.xml` of `bom`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- parent coordinates -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>in.packagename.mint</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectname</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>projectname-bom</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <junit.jupiter.migration-support.version>5.7.0</junit.jupiter.migration-support.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.13</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-migrationsupport</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.jupiter.migration-support.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

I have tried deleting `.m2` folder and building all these `bom`, `common-test`, etc. separately and runnning `mvn install` but this dependency issue is not resolved and not able to import it in `service` test folders.

Comment: This is all confusing. First of all, which of your modules has a dependency on which other (posting the POMs would be good)? Secondly, every module should declare its own test dependencies.

Comment: Updated. Please check again.

Comment: Didn't get you. Actually, is this not a common way to make spring boot project?

Comment: Sorry, misread the POMs. Please first correct the typos in the artifactIds.

Comment: I think we need to see the service pom as well.